# Is there a possibility that null is inserted when add_column with default option, and without null:false

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

When I migrate file to add column to existing data,

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Is there a possibility to the value `null` to `admin` column?

If I add `null: false` option like this,

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false, null: false
  end
end
```

I can understand that `admin` column never contains `null`.

However If I add column with `default` option and without `null: false` option, I would like to know the possibility that `admin` contains `null`.

The Database is MySQL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with SQLite, but I think it will be applied same for MySQL.

If you use `default` option and without `null: false` option, it is possible that admin can contain `null`:

[image]

If you use both `default` and `null` option, it is clearly that it is not possible to contain null:

[image]